# iOS CGAffineTransform odd behavior

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to simply animate a view from one position to a another, using the code below, but the animation is not smooth. There is a "pop" in the animation. It moves up quickly before moving down for example.

Can anyone let me know if there is something wrong with my setup?

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            [_label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 88)];
            transformState = 1;
   }];
```

Thanks for reading!

If you have a minute please download this very simple test project, so you can easily see the issue, and if you do, thanks so much for taking the time.

http://owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/TransformTest.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view controller has autolayout turned on in your storyboard, and [autolayout can interact with the transform in unexpected ways.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943107/how-do-i-adjust-the-anchor-point-of-a-calayer-when-auto-layout-is-being-used/14105757#14105757)

Either turn autolayout off, or consider [using the autolayout constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559677/animating-a-view-created-in-ib-using-autolayout/14698401#14698401) to do your animation.